# Why deployed create-react-app returns 404 error upon reload?

Tags: reactjs, deployment

After deploying my create-react-app to its own subdomain (contents of the build directory copied to root), the app runs perfectly except upon reloading the page, when it throws a 404 error.

I set the "homepage" property in package.json to its subdomain, ie., "http://sub.domain.com". I also tried setting homepage to ".", and even removing it altogether.

Might this have to do with how subdomains are configured on my host?

Answer (score 1):

suppose you have a node.js backend.
In your routes file define a handler that will serve all the 'unmatched' paths(must be the last one):

```
 //other routes go here

app.get('*', function (request, response){
//in here just send the index.html
  response.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, './frontend/public', 'index.html'))
});
```

Comment: No node.js backend. It's served from a typical hosting service running apache.

Comment: well hope you get the main idea

Comment: You need to configure Apache to serve `index.html` for all unrecognised paths, and not just for the root. Search for "Apache single page applications".

Comment: That was it. Thank you Dan!