# How can I properly use the res.sendFile for my MERN APP, I get an error every time I refresh it

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mern

So I created a post previous day and deleted it because it's unproper and also unclear, so right now, I'll try to write it properly.

So I created a MERN app using render.com, but the problem is every time I refresh the the webpage, I get an `error / not found`. Example. I went to a specific user id , I can view his the profile but once I refresh/reload, it gets an error. So I created a two separate folder and two different GitHub repo.

I uploaded the front end as a static website in render.com

Github: [Front Site](https://github.com/cruz-emman/front)

Website [Front Website](https://tua-mern-app.onrender.com/)

So for the backend, I follow this thread and [Why deployed create-react-app returns 404 error upon reload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43808728/why-deployed-create-react-app-returns-404-error-upon-reload). But I don't know how can I properly use `res.sendFile` because I'm using a different root directory as well as different github repo.

Github : https://github.com/cruz-emman/back

Website: https://mern-tua-ebenta.onrender.com/

I tried to use this, and I admit that I'm doing it wrong because I don't know how can I do it.

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'../client/build')));
app.get('*', (req,res) => res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname,'../', 'client','build','index.html'))
```

**EDIT: TYPO**

Answer (score 0):

After trial and error, I finally solved the answer, so what I did here is merge the two folders. [image]

After putting it in a single directory, I run `npm run build` for client folder. After that, I put this code inside `index.js`

```
const __dirname = path.resolve()
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/client/build')));
app.get("*",(req,res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/client/build/index.html'));
})
```

After that, I push it to a new git repository, and run `web service` for `render.com`