# My website gets an error/empty when I refresh after deployment, MERN STACK

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, deployment, mern

This is my previous question. [How can I properly use the res.sendFile for my MERN APP, I get an error every time I refresh it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74959392/how-can-i-properly-use-the-res-sendfile-for-my-mern-app-i-get-an-error-every-ti), it works there.

What happened here is the same thing, I still get an error when I refresh to a certain site even though I just followed the previous work. I decided to continue my previous work, and apply it to my previous works, but it stills the same even though followed the `express.static`

```
root
|--- client
|--- model
|--- route
|--- server
|--- index.js
|--- package.json
```

index.js

```
const __dirname = path.resolve()
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/client/build')));
app.get("*",(req,res) => {
    etag: false
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/client/build/index.html'));
})
```

And at the same time, I used this inside my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "tua_thesis_rework",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "npm install && cd client && npm install && npm run build",
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@mui/x-data-grid": "^5.17.17",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.0",
    "mongodb": "^4.13.0",
    "mongoose": "^6.8.2",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.20"
  }
}
```

Webiste: https://tua-ebenta.onrender.com/

Github Repo: https://github.com/cruz-emman/revison1

Comment: I took a quick look into your repo, why are you jamming everything in the same workspace? and the reason why your client shows an empty page after build because cra static uses absolute paths, not relative ones, so your index.html will not be able to load the required js files

Comment: @tbc the reason I jam it everything in the same route because I was getting confused on calling `scripts` inside `package.json`, I was following a tutorial from youtube and apply it to mine.

Comment: And addition to that is, I followed the same step I used when the other `mernapp` works.

Comment: thanks @tbc , I followed your statement and fix problem!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, I went to my `client/package.json` and then remove the `"homepage:" "."`!
Big thanks to @tbc, I hope I can tag you here!